# NullPointerException in Android JSONParser

Tags: java, android, nullreferenceexception

I have an android application that crashes whenever I press the Login button; I keep getting a Null Pointer Exception in my JSONParser. I really hope you can help.

Here is my UserFunctions.java:

```
package com.example.sabre9.library;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;

public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    // Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp 
    // use http://10.0.2.2/ to connect to your localhost ie http://localhost/
    private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/Sabre1/";
    //private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/Sabre1/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    //private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(loginURL, "POST", params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Register Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    /*
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));


        //getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(registerURL, "POST", params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }*/

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     **/
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }
}
```

JSONParser.java:

```
package com.example.sabre9.library;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {

        }

        // function get json from url
        // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
        public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

                // Making HTTP request
                try {

                        // check for request method
                        if(method == "POST"){
                                // request method is POST
                                // defaultHttpClient
                                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                                is = httpEntity.getContent();

                        }else if(method == "GET"){
                                // request method is GET
                                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                                url += "?" + paramString;
                                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                        }                      


                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();
                        json = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }

                // try parse the string to a JSON object
                try {
                        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }

                // return JSON String
                return jObj;

        }
}
```

And here are my logcat errors:

```
02-13 03:15:01.921: E/Buffer Error(1263):   Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
02-13 03:15:01.931: E/JSON Parser(1263):    Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
02-13 03:15:02.891: E/Buffer Error(1263):   Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
02-13 03:15:02.891: E/JSON Parser(1263):    Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Edit: My LoginActivity.java:

```
package com.example.sabre9;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.sabre9.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.sabre9.library.UserFunctions;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnLogin;
    //Button btnLinkToRegister;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    //private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    //private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                if (params.length != 2)
                        return null;
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(params[0], params[1]);
                return json;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                try {
            if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Store user details in SQLite Database
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                    // Clear all previous From in database
                    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                    // Launch Main Screen
                    Intent main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                    // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                    main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(main);

                    // Close Login Screen
                    finish();
                }else{
                    // Error in login
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        //btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();                
                new MyAsyncTask().execute(email, password);
            }

        });

         //Link to Register Screen
        /*btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });*/
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could tell us where the exception happens, that'd be great.

Comment: When you get an exception, try using `Log.e(tag, message, throwable)` so you get the stack trace of the exception written to the LogCat as well.

Comment: If I actually could tell, I would. The thing is, I cannot. Those entries are the only ones in my logcat.

Comment: Your `null` is probably `is`, which means you're getting empty results from your server. You should verify you're getting `200 OK` in your code by checking `httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`

Comment: At which line you got NPE?

Comment: it doesn't show in the logcat. However I believe the error comes from my makeHTTPRequest function; I don't know what specifically though.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a JSON response?

Comment: How do I know? Sorry for my ignorance, I am new to Android.

Comment: Check if your 'reader' or your 'is' is null.

Comment: if (reader == null) { do something... }

Answer (score 1):

Your `java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null` occurs >= Android 3.0 because networking is not allowed on the main(UI) thread, unless overridden via StrictMode policy.  Try:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Note that as a result, `httpClient.execute(httpPost);` will lock up the system pretty bad as it waits for the response.  (Instead, you might do that in an AsyncTask so it doesn't lock up the main thread.)  Hope this helps.

Comment: **StrictMode** can only use for far away for network operatin error. Its not a right way. Because you can't use it in your live app. It can just avoid network related error..

Comment: I have edited my post so as to include the code for my LoginActivity. Any idea on where best to insert the code you have provided? My AsyncTask is stated there also.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this error. Seems that through a very embarassing brain fart I have forgotten to include in my manifest file the internet permissions needed. Also, I have tweaked my php files a little. Thank you for the answers anyways :)